# How to find the path of a node in parse tree

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

I used Stanford parser and got a parse tree for one sentence. How can I get the path of every node?

For example, here is my parser tree:

(ROOT

(S

```
(NP (PRP He))
(VP (VBD entered)
  (NP (DT the) (NN door)))
(. .)))
```

When I input VP, the program gives me the path of VP node: ROOT->S->VP;
When I input PRP, the program gives me the path of PRP node: ROOT->S->NP->PRP.

I have no ideas about this issue. Do need your help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928739/how-to-get-the-root-node-in-stanford-parse-tree/35012082

Comment: I tried this answer. But it returned null. I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the solution.

I first used DFS to reach every node and then used a method called

> pathNodeToNode(node1, node2)

. This method is from `StanfordNLP tree class`. Here is the method link https://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp-3.5.0/edu/stanford/nlp/trees/Tree.html

Hope this may help someone else.